# Latex: smaller Greek letters in math mode

Tags: plugin-vim-latex, conceal, plugin-vimtex

In `init.vim`, I use `vimtex` and `text-conceal`, but it seems Greek letters and math operators look smaller. Here is an example:

[image]

But when the cursor moves away, the math mode looks like this:

[image].

From this, the greek letters and operators `\beta, \inn, \mathbb{R}, \sum` all become smaller. I was wondering where this issue may occur? Thanks.

Comment: Could be your font?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks. Yes, I just adapted the font size in the preference setting!

Comment: Please add an answer with details on how you solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

I adapted the font in the preference shown below:

[image]

In the Text section, the font size under Non-ASCII Font will change the font size of greek letters and other math operators like \mathbb{E}, \mathscr{F} etc.